# setting up an NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app delegate I look for a plist to import and turn it into an NSMutableDictionary.

```
NSLog(@"Reading session file from main bundle");
    NSString *plistPath = [Utilities localPathForFileName:kSessionFile];
    NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
    temp = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                            propertyListFromData:plistXML
                            mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                            format:&format
                            errorDescription:&errorDesc];
```

My NSMutableDictionary is then saved into a singleton for access throughout the app

```
[[self model] setStorage:temp];
```

That all works fine and allows me to add objects to the dictionary at will because of the mutabilityOption. I also write it out to a plist. Second time the app opens it finds the saved plist and reads from there.

My question is, how can I initially create the NSMutableDictionary with the same mutabilityOptions WITHOUT reading it in from a pList? If I could do that, then I could also erase the data in the dictionary at will. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Surely all you need to do is this:

```
 [[self model] setStorage:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];
```

Comment: Thanks. Will that give me a dictionary that I can add items to arbitrarily?

Comment: Yes, it expands as needed. If you know about how many you think you'll need as a minimum, you can use - dictionaryWithCapacity: